# how to create a data frame without using pivot table to make the execution faster?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I have dataframe with 3 columns testname, serial_id and result. I have created a pivot table using code below
Testname is of type object, serial_id is of type object and result is of type "int16"

```
pvt_df = df.pivot(index='testname',columns='serial_id', values='result')
```

This takes about 60 to 70 seconds when i have a data frame that is of shape (6144229 x 3). I want to know if there is a way to do this faster. any help will be appreciated

A faster approach will be appreciated as the current time taken makes it not worth it when i have about 1 million unique serial_id's
and i also run into the issue of "ValueError("Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow")" when i have more than 500k parts. Chunking data for pivot table makes it even longer, so need  a faster way to do this

To add more details:
I want to create a new dataframe that has testname as index, serial_id as columns and result from the tests as values. after this i would like to take that dataframe and run jaccard similarity.

```
data = [['test1', 'SERIAL1','0'], ['test2', 'SERIAL2','1'], ['test3', 'SERIAL3', '0'], ['test4', 'SERIAL4', '1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['testname', 'serial_id','result'])

pvt_df = df.pivot(index='testname',columns='serial_id', values='result')

output expected:

serial_id   SERIAL1 SERIAL2 SERIAL3 SERIAL4
testname                
test1   0   NaN NaN NaN
test2   NaN 1   NaN NaN
test3   NaN NaN 0   NaN
test4   NaN NaN NaN 1
```

I do have a big dataframe with the same format as above which i cannot share but the shape as i mentioned is big (6144229 x 3). so any advice on how to convert original dataframe to the pvt_df without using pivot?

Comment: The `df.pivot()` is likely not what causes the slow timing, but the fact that Pandas can't take advantage of numpy's speed on a series of type `object`. What are you trying to achieve here? Can you provide a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: @ddejohn i have updated a sample example. Yes i do have 2 objects fields which are not letting pandas take advantage of numpy array pivot table. So any help you can provide would be good